# I think I'm missing something here -- string.replace()

Tags: java, string, replace

I have the code

```
String txt = "<p style=\"margin-top: 0\">";
txt.replace("style=\"margin-top: 0\"","class=\"style_" + i + "\"");
```

In a for loop (which is what the i is for), but when I run this, nothing gets replaced. Am I using this wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
String txt = "<p style=\"margin-top: 0\">";
txt = txt.replace("style=\"margin-top: 0\"","class=\"style_" + i + "\"");
```

"String" is an immutable type, which means that methods on a String do not change the String itself.  More info here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object.

Comment: Oh wow. I can't believe I missed this. I think I need to take a break. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The [`replace`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) method does not modify the string on which it is called but instead returns the reference to the modified string.

If you want `txt` to refer to the modified string you can do:

```
txt = txt.replace("style=\"margin-top: 0\"","class=\"style_" + i + "\"");
```

If you want `txt` to continue to refer to the original string and want a different reference to refer to the changed string you can do:

```
String new_txt = txt.replace("style=\"margin-top: 0\"","class=\"style_" + i + "\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

String is a immutable class, which means instance methods of a String object don't alter the string itself. You have to gather the return value of those instance methods.